# WooCommerce: Product Price Range Display Format in Subscriptio plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have set up 2 products which are variable subscriptions product types. These products have the option to purchase one-time or a subscription-based version.
On the product pages, we can see the price displayed as "$33.28 - 35.04 / month" (check the link here http://harparams.sg-host.com/)

The issue is that this gives an impression that we only work on subscription-based products, and we'd like to delete the "/month" part of the format.

We checked the file "rp-sub-pricing.class.php" and found what we think might be the solution, but we don't have enough knowledge to change it on our end. From line 121 to 151 there is the following:

```
// Prepare selected price for display
$selected_display_price = wc_price(RightPress_Product_Price_Display::prepare_product_price_for_display($subscription_product->get_wc_product(), $selected_price, false, true));
// Child prices differ
if (RightPress_Product_Price::prices_differ($min_reference_price, $max_reference_price)) {
// Format recurring amount for display
$display_price = RP_SUB_Pricing::format_recurring_amount_for_display($selected_display_price, $subscription_product->get_billing_cycle_length(), $subscription_product->get_billing_cycle_period());
// Apply extra formatting and set to main variable
$display_price = sprintf(__('From %s', 'subscriptio'), $display_price);
}
// Child prices do not differ but other settings differ (simplified display price will be used)
else if (count($settings_hashes) > 1) {
// Format recurring amount for display
$display_price = RP_SUB_Pricing::format_recurring_amount_for_display($selected_display_price, $subscription_product->get_billing_cycle_length(), $subscription_product->get_billing_cycle_period());
}
// Child prices and settings do not differ
else {
// Format subscription product display price
$display_price = RP_SUB_Pricing::format_subscription_product_display_price($display_price, $subscription_product);
}
// Allow developers to override and set new display price
$display_price = apply_filters('subscriptio_subscription_product_variable_formatted_price', $display_price, $subscription_product);
}
return $display_price;
}
```

Maybe just deleting the get_billing_cycle_length() or get_billing_cycle_period() could work?

Is there a way to add this as a filter in functions.php so we don't lose it on next updates?

Sidenote: we are using Subscriptio Plugin by Rightpress https://codecanyon.net/item/subscriptio-woocommerce-subscriptions/8754068

Comment: As this is a closed commercial non official plugin, your question has very poor chances to get a useful answer.

Comment: Any chance you can review this code? We've been trying to set it up but it doesn't work and we don't know why.

add_filter('subscriptio_subscription_product_variable_formatted_price', 'subscriptio_subscription_product_variable_formatted_price_change');

function subscriptio_subscription_product_variable_formatted_price_change($var) {
   $var = preg_replace('/\/month/', '', $var);
    return $var;
}